# Why are all my eclipse wizards empty/not working

Tags: java, eclipse, import, wizard

I'm using a brand new Lenovo Yoga 900 with 512 Gb SSD and 16 Gb RAM. The problem now is the following: I'd like to use the notebook for development with eclipse. I have installed the Java 8 SDK and eclipse mars.

I allready have a couple of projects on my disk, developed on other computers. Now I want to import these projects and use the File -> Import dialog. When the dialog opens, it is completely empty. There is nothin I can do except closing the dialog again. The same happens when I try to create a new project with file->new project...

Also I tryed the same with eclipse luna, but the behaviour is exactly the same.

[image: Empty Import Wizard]

Comment: Is this a Windows machine, and it's brand new? There's never been Eclipse on it before?  Where'd you point the workspace folder to, is that a writable folder for Eclipse?

Comment: Try running Eclipse as Administrator. Right-Click on the Eclipse desktop icon then select:  Run as administrator

Comment: Correct, it's a new notebook and eclipse wasn't installed before. The account I'm using is an administrator account plus I tried to explicitly start eclipse as an administrator. The folder where the projects are in are in my user directory so I don't assume some kind of permission problem. By the way, the same problem appears when I choose File -> new Project... The wizard is empty I stead of showing me some options which kind of project I'd like to create.

Answer (score 1):

This may be caused by windows resolution problems. I have 4k resolution monitor, maybe that could play a role here. My Eclipse IDE doesn't completely respond to this resolution, waiting for new upgrades to take this into consideration. A simple solution to this issue that I have recently discovered is just maximizing "Select a Wizard" window and you will see those options.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue. There are some solutions out there but those cant work because they are for the nView Desktop Management, which the lenovo yoga 900 doesnt have. We have the intel graphic.

Comment: i found the soulution for this, you have to change the text scale from windows, because of its nativ 175% so right click on desktop->screensettings(in german "Anzeigeeinstellungen")-sizing text scale, 200% works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Windows' display settings. The window is resized to the bare minimum, causing most of the menu to disappear.

The wizard content is still actually there, you just need to resize the window until it appears. Hover your mouse over the bottom-right corner of the wizard window until the mouse pointer changes into the resizing icon (the two diagonal arrows) and drag and drop outwards.

To prevent it from initialising wizards this small you could (as mentioned in a comment above) change your display settings to a larger font size, but that messes up your whole Windows imo.

I'll look into a different way to solve this.

**UPDATE**:

The 32-bit version of Eclipse can be run in Windows compatibility mode. I've not tested this myself, but it seems that when run in that mode (I'd try Windows 7 first) Eclipse will scale everything as it should.

At this point, the 64-bit version does not support compatibility mode - so unless you can solve it with the native Windows scaling utility, there is no solution yet.